# Summing of Boolean 'Trues' in a Case Statement at MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, case

I would like to ask you whether I can count the 'Trues' in a Case statement.

```
t_1 As (
SELECT *,
-- Spot Guide not to be Empty 
CASE 
    WHEN (total_spots_number <> 0 AND (spot1_availability IS NULL AND spot2_availability IS NULL AND spot3_availability IS NULL)) THEN 'cannot be empty'
    WHEN (total_spots_number = 1 AND SUM(spot1_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot2_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot3_availability IS NOT NULL) <> 1) THEN 'one spot is incomplete'
    WHEN (total_spots_number = 2 AND SUM(spot1_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot2_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot3_availability IS NOT NULL) <> 2) THEN 'two spots are incomplete'
    WHEN (total_spots_number = 3 AND SUM(spot1_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot2_availability IS NOT NULL AND spot3_availability IS NOT NULL) <> 3) THEN 'three spots are incomplete'
    ELSE 'nothing to check'
END AS QA_Check_1
FROM Main_Data
)
SELECT * FROM t_1
```

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: Can you post the actual code instead of a screenshot? Also, this looks like SQL, but the question isn't tagged as SQL.

Comment: hello. i apologize for the unclear post. it is my first one. I posted the code and the language i use. for sure, the SUM cannot show any result, but this I want to do is to summarize the Trues in these conditions.

Comment: Is there a missing `WITH` before the CTE?

Comment: Hey. there is a WITH Main_Data As (Select etc. etc.). and the t_1 is a CTE too. I have no problem with the CTEs, but with the Sum. I will try what you did and come back with feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a conditional expression is `1` if it's true, so you can simply add them.

```
WITH availability AS (
    SELECT (spot1_availability IS NOT NULL) + (spot2_availability IS NOT NULL) + (spot3_availability IS NOT NULL) AS availability_count
    FROM Main_Data
)
```

Comment: if the spot1_availability is not Null then we get True but not 1s or 0s. Finally, i did it with case statement and transformed the data to 1s and 0s in order to get their sum. Thank you for your kind response.